# Android Development where to start (IDE and books title required)

Tags: android, mobile

I am starting into the development of mobile app. I want to start with Android. I am planning to develop application using emulator.

Please recommend me where to start, which book I should follow? Which IDE and tools?

I am use to Microsoft development stack with 5 years of experience.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272764/where-to-start-with-programming-android-applications so you can look for good answers there as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best place to start is:

http://developer.android.com

The "Dev Guide".

Android is one of the best documentet Environments IMHO. And this is not only technical. You get a huge load of examples there as well.

I definetly recommend "Eclipse" with the "ADT" (Android Developer Tools). All of that is documented in high detail in the mentioned developer Guide.

Answer (score 0):

You should work through the Android development tutorials at http://developer.android.com/resources/browser.html?tag=tutorial and go from there.  Eclipse is the standard IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Motodev Studio from Motorola is a good IDE. http://developer.motorola.com/docstools/motodevstudio/download/

About books, Android documentatio it's self a good reference.

http://developer.android.com/guide/basics/what-is-android.html

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse with ADT is the de-facto standard for writing Android apps.

Googles, developer guide, is the best introduction.

Once out of the learning curve, I highly recommend using a phone for development, and not the emulator, as it tends to be slow, and has many things it does not actually emulate.